# Bug when use value as children of TextInput [React Native]

Tags: ios, react-native, textinput

I'm having some problems using  component in `React Native 0.70.2`.
Specifically I need to put the text like this  {children} , instead of passing a value prop, because I need to manipulate text for creating a mention text input.

> Here's a video of what happen: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/64473929/194781923-7a314cef-6522-424d-a085-9a70478bd390.MP4

Here's my code: https://snack.expo.dev/@pietroputelli/bbbed6

Is there any path to solve this bug?
Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

You should add

```
onChangeText={(text) => {
    setValue(text)
}}
```

Now it will only rerender the text once per keystroke.

If you change the value directly like you do, the state will update first when you enter a keystroke, then the component rerenders, and will set the state again with the value+value, which will trigger rerenders exponentially.